# updating password but unable to login from updated password in django

Tags: python, django

updating user password first fetching username from URL & updating password.

not sure is this code working or not because i am unable to login from the old password again & even with the updated password too.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def change_password2(request, user_username):
    var_username =  get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
#getting username from url

    u = User.objects.get(username__exact=var_username)

    password = request.POST.get('password_update', False)
    u.set_password(password)
    b = u.save()

    update_session_auth_hash(request, b)  
    messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
    # return redirect('change_password')
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password2.html')
```

change_password2.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/password2/">
  {% csrf_token %}
<input type="password" name="password_update">

<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

ursl.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.account, name='account'),
        path('account/', views.account, name='account'),

    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('password2/<slug:user_username>/', views.change_password2, name='change_password2'),

]
```

Tried in incognito but not sure its because of cache.

Comment: Hi,

Without all the code (url.py) i can only make assuption.

1. Where did you get `user_username` ? 
2. dont update the password if password is `False`

Comment: am updating question please have a look.

Comment: By all means **use the contrib.auth views** for this - your implementation is a complete disaster and just an opened gateway for script kiddies (anyone can change any password to anything without any verification).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i know i just completed my tuts & now practicing. this is just for practice purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
u = User.objects.get(username__exact=var_username)
# ...
b = u.save()
update_session_auth_hash(request, b)
```

`Model.save()` returns `None` (hint: as a general rule, in Python, a method that changes an object in place usually returns `None`), so you're passing `None` to `update_session_auth_hash()`. You want this instead:

```
u = User.objects.get(username__exact=var_username)
u.set_password(the_new_password_here)
u.save()
update_session_auth_hash(request, u)
```

I can't tell if that's the only point preventing your code from (kind of) working, but that's one obvious blocker.

Now as I mentionned, your code is a mess and a **huge** security breach - actually it lets anyone changes anyone else's password to whatever...  You states that it's for practice only but then I suggest you take time to read `contrib.auth` source to find out how to do this securely.

wrt/ the mess part:

```
# First point: 'user_username' is redundant to say the least,
# and since usernames can be changed you should use the user.id
# instead - or actually not use anything, cf below
#
# Second point: your view should be restricted to authenticated
# users only (using the `login_required` decorator being the
# simple and obvious way)
#
# Third point: only the admins and the (authenticated) user himself
# should be allowed to change the user's password. Since admins
# already can do this in the (django) admin, here you actually want
# to only allow the current authenticated user to change his own
# password, so you shouldn't pass the user id nor username and
# only work on `request.user`
#  
# Fourth point: this view should either test on the request
# method and only performs updates on a POST request, or
# just plain refuse any other method than POST (there's
# a decorator for this too). Remember that GET requests
# **MUST** be idempotent.


def change_password2(request, user_username):
    # this returns the User matching `user_username`
    var_username =  get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)

    # this does the exact same thing AGAIN (so it's totally useless)
    # and actually only works by accident  - you're passing the user
    # object as argument where a username (string) is expected, 
    # and it only works because the string representation of a 
    # User is the username and the ORM lookup will force 
    # the argument to string.
    u = User.objects.get(username__exact=var_username)

    # Here you accept just anything as password, and
    # if you don't have one you'll try to use `False`
    # instead, which is probably not what you want.
    # 
    # You should actually use a Django form to validate
    # you inputs... 
    password = request.POST.get('password_update', False)

    u.set_password(password)
```

etc...

Comment: thanks for reply, but i am so sorry (am new to django) i didn't understand your answer, can you please teach me by fixing this code, because i tried but still getting same problem.

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand in "`Model.save()` returns `None`", but if you're struggling with this you should probably step back from django for a time and first learn CS101.  NB: I don't mean to sound harsh or patronizing here, it's just that understanding functions return values is really so basic that it's taken for granted (in django's doc) that you understand what this means.

Comment: nm, actually my english is very bad, i have to google for words. Cant understand english sentences quickly i have to read it twice or thrice, thanks for your help. actually i spent almost 7 hour today. may be my mind is stuck at one point

Comment: Uhu sorry for the misunderstanding  - but you really need to learn English then...